# If $x:y=2:1$ and $y:z=2:1$, then $x$,$y$,$z$ are continued proportional? and/or $z:x=1:4$? and/or $y^2+z x=4yz$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, ratio

[image: This is the math, Here continued proportional means ordered proportional]

I will prove that I attempted this math by listing the things that I know.

1. $y=2z$
2. $x=2z^2$
3. $x=yz$

Also, did you notice something? If $x=8,  y=4,z=2$ then everything works out.

I figured this while attempting the math.

But the problem is I don't know how to justify my hypothesis. That's why I'm asking the question.

If there's any problem in my question please inform me.

Comment: Here continued proportional means ordered proportional, also can anyone suggest some tags for this question please?

Comment: Most of the 'things that you know' are false! Consider for example $x=40,y=20,z=10$; then $x \ne 2z^2$, and $x \ne yz$.

Comment: "Here continued proportional means ordered proportional".  Okay.   What does "ordered proportional" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x:y = 2:1$ so $x = 2y$.

$y:z = 2:1$ so $y = 2z$.

So $x  = 2y = 2(2z) = 4z$ and so $x:z = 4: 1$ and $z:x = 1:4$.

So $ii$ is true.

Does $y^2 + xy = 4xy$?  Well, $y^2 = (2z)^2 = 4z^2$ and $xy  = (4z)(2z) = 8z^2$ so $y^2 + xy = 4z^2 + 8z^2 = 12z^2$.  Meanwhile $4xy = 4(4z)(2z) = 32z^2$.  Does $12z^2 = 32z^2$?  Only if $z= 0$, which it can not as $y:z = 2:1$.  So $iii$)

What about $i$?  $x,y,z$ are quantuum porpoises[1]?  I don't know what that means.  But and $ii$ is true and $iii$ is false that means 1) is the only possible option.

1. $y = 2z$.

True.

2. $x = 2z^2$.

False.

3. $x = yz$

What the .....???????

====

[1]  Does "continued proportional" mean that $x:y = y:z$?  Well, as $x:y = 2:1$ and $y:z = 2:1$ that is simply true.  There's  nothing to argue.  It's just true.

Comment: Yes ordered proportional means just that, according to my book.

Answer (score 0):

From the condition we have that $x=2y; y=2z$. This yields that $x=4z$ and so *ii)* must be a true assertation. Now to check the validity of *iii)* just write everything in terms of $z$. You would get:

$$y^2 + zx = (2z)^2 + z\cdot 4z = 8z = 4 (2z)z = 4zy$$

Thus *iii)* is a true claim too. For the first claim **continued proportional** is a bit vague. If it means that the variables are ordered in increasing order then it's wrong. As you can take $x=-4, y=-2, z= -1$. Nevertheless we must have $x > y > z$ or $x < y < z$ depending on the sign of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   x:y = 2:1, \ y:z = 2:1
   &\implies \dfrac xy = 2, \ \dfrac yz = 2 \\
   &\implies \dfrac xz =  \dfrac xy \cdot \dfrac yz= 4\\
   &\implies x:z=4:1 \\
\hline
   &\implies x:y = y:z \\
   &\implies  x:y :: y:z \\
\hline
   &\implies \dfrac xy + \dfrac yz = 4 \\
   &\implies y^2 + zx = 4yz 
\end{align}

So all three are true.

Comment: This addresses truth of one of the three statements which the Question asks about.  Were you skipping the other two parts, or were you implying that they are not true?

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$x:y=2:1 \iff x:y=2:1=4:2.$$
It implies:
$$x:y=4:2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ y:z=2:1 \Rightarrow x:y:z=4:2:1 \Rightarrow x=4n,y=2n,z=n.$$
Hence:
$$\begin{align}i)& \ x:y:z=4:2:1 \ \ \text{(continued proportional)};\\
ii)& \ z:x=n:4n=1:4;\\
iii)& \ y^2+zx=4yz \iff (2n)^2+n(4n)=4(2n)n \iff 8n^2=8n^2. \end{align}$$
Hence, the correct answer is $4)$.